# Joomla Custom component with sample form in admin

Tags: joomla, components, administrator

I need a sample form in administrator having add,edit,delete options to manage "success stories" in my web app.

I searched to get sample component to install.

If i get that, i will change form according to my app & table too.

Please help me by giving link resource that suits my requirement. I am sorry to ask this, i am new to joomla.

Thanks in advance,
Sunil.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Joomla Component Creator: http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/